# Multiple window event listeners having a weird effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cant seem to get the event resize event listener to fire for the code with body background as red the second one. My code is below If you view the site at [link-here](http://tech-heros.meteor.com) when you start at the small size and resize until the background changes red. clicking the services button does nothing, however if you resize from the large size down to the red, it auto opens the nav and the toggle click works. Not sure why.

```
var resizeMethod = function(){
    if (document.body.clientWidth > 1400) {

      $("body").css("background", "purple");



      $(".first , .drop-down li").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".drop-down").addClass("drop-down-visible");
        $(".first a").css("background", "#8F8F8F");
      }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(".drop-down").removeClass("drop-down-visible");
        $(".first a").css("background", "#CDCDCD");
      });


      $(".icon-1 , .info-1").hover(function() {
        $(".info-1").addClass("info-visible");
      }, function() {
      $(".info-1").removeClass("info-visible");

      });

      $(".icon-2 , .info-2").hover(function() {
        $(".info-2").addClass("info-visible");
      }, function() {
      $(".info-2").removeClass("info-visible");

      });

      $(".icon-3 , .info-3").hover(function() {
        $(".info-3").addClass("info-visible");
      }, function() {
      $(".info-3").removeClass("info-visible");

      });

      $(".icon-4 , .info-4").hover(function() {
        $(".info-4").addClass("info-visible");
      }, function() {
      $(".info-4").removeClass("info-visible");

      });

    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeMethod, true);

  var resizeMethodM = function(){

    if(document.body.clientWidth < 1400) {


    $("body").css("background", "red");

      $(".first").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(".mainNav .drop-down").toggleClass("drop-down-visible-m");

    });

    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeMethodM, true);
```

Comment: You're attaching hundreds or even thousands of different kind of listeners to some elements. `resize` is triggered tens of times per second, and every handler attaches a bunch of new listeners...

Comment: Why can't you use only resizeMethod with if ... else

Comment: I tried if else, and had the same effect. So i split it up to test. What is suggested to do so that the menu has a hover state when resized in large screen and click state when resized in smaller state. I would ideally like not to have that many click listeners?